# Doctrine: A new entity was found through the relationship with selected elements

Tags: symfony

In a symfony command script, i find entities like this :

```
$this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:House')->findBy(...);
```

Foreach element, i call a service method with my element as an argument.
In my Service, i have an error when i try to create an element linked to the "house"object

this doesn't works :

```
$glass = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Glass')->findOneBy(['house' => $house->getId(), 'name' => $name]);
if (! $glass instanceof Glass) {
    $newGlass= new Glass($house, $name);
    $this->em->persist($newGlass);
    $this->em->flush();
}
```

this works but i don't want to have to find again my existing house i already founded in my command script :

```
$existingHouse = $this->em->getRepository('House')->find($house->getId());
$glass = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Glass')->findOneBy(['house' => $house->getId(), 'name' => $name]);
if (! $glass instanceof Glass) {
    $newGlass= new Glass($existingHouse, $name);
    $this->em->persist($newGlass);
    $this->em->flush();
}
```

Can you help me to understang what's wrong ?

Glass constructor

```
public function __construct(House $house, string $name)
{
    $this->name= $name;
    $house->addGlass($this);
    $this->house= $house;
}
```

house orm file :

```
oneToMany:
    glasses:
        targetEntity: Glass
        mappedBy: house
        cascade: ["persist"]
```

glass orm file :

```
manyToOne:
    house:
        targetEntity: House
        cascade: {  }
        fetch: LAZY
        mappedBy: null
        inversedBy: glasses
        joinColumns:
            house_id:
                referencedColumnName: id
        orphanRemoval: false
```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to fetch a house from the Glass repository ... 
  $existingHouse = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Glass')->find($house->getId());

Comment: my mistake, copy/paste error when writing the post. But the bug still persists

Comment: Where does your original $house come form?  Session perhaps?  Is it new-ed?  If $house was not loaded via the entity manager then you can save yourself a query using a reference: $houseReference = $em->getReference('House',$houseId) and then Glass($houseReference, $name);

Comment: One more thing to check.  Verify your Glass constructor is calling House::addGlass($this);

Comment: `Where does your original $house come form` -> when i execute my command, it is already in my database so it just comes from a findBy, and i get the entity manager with `$this->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager')`. And `House::addGlass($this);` is called in  my construtor, it is in my example. If you want the details of the "add" method, tell me but it was generated by symfony

Comment: Apologies.  Should have read your posted code more closely.  The error message is typically generated when the entities are not properly cross linked but it looks like you have everything covered as long as you are not somehow overwriting your original $house object.  Just for grins, you might check if ($house === $existingHouse) .  They should be identical objects since the entity manager caches it's objects.